# Dart editor “source not available” in linux?

Tags: linux, dart, dart-editor

When I try to debug a dart application on Linux Mint 17 using Dart Editor 1.8.5.release (STABLE) with Dart SDK version 1.8.5, it shows me the message "Source not Available for ". This occurs for any brake-point set inside a library.

I tested the same in windows and it works correctly.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I think you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: I get this too. It happens whenever the code steps into some native VM code. I usually just click "step" a couple of times, and then you get back into the source code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer:  Günter, don't you think that this is possible an user problem? I deleted similar question because you was very nervous in the comments and you don't believe in the `eternal problems with Dart`

Comment: I have the same problem since the first date when `Dart Editor 1.8.5.release (STABLE) ` was released. I did not create the issue because the developers will not make corrections in version 1.8.5, because soon will available the next version (1.9.0). Unfortunately, I'm sure that it (the new release 1.9.0) will contain already the other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot solve this problem. At least without the choosing the other version of the Dart Editor to use.
This is a bug and other people also have the same problem.